# ine 2, column 1 expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'

Tags: docker

My Docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal
    ports:
      - "3306:80"
    volumes:
    - drupal-modules:/var/www/html/modules \
    - drupal-profiles:/var/www/html/profiles \
    - drupal-sites:/var/www/html/sites \
    - drupal-themes:/var/www/html/themes \
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypasswd

 volumes:
     drupal-modules:
     drupal-profiles:
     drupal-sites:
     drupal-themes:
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this?

Comment: Can you please tell us whats happening? Please format your post so its easier to read and understand.

Comment: The backslashes in the `volumes` section look suspicious to me.